# What is the most elegant way to slightly tweak what the member function does in Common Lisp?

Tags: refactoring, common-lisp, primitive

The member function works like this with strings:

```
CL-USER> (member "a" '("a" "b" "c") :test #'equalp)
("a" "b" "c")
CL-USER> (member "a" '( "b" "c") :test #'equalp)
NIL
```

I would like to slightly change its behavior. When the element is **not** part of the list, I would like to have as a return the **element itself** and not `nil`. Moreover, if the element is indeed part of the list, I would like to have `nil`.

So, something like:

```
CL-USER> (tweaked-member "a" '("a" "b" "c") :test #'equalp)
NIL
CL-USER> (tweaked-member "a" '( "b" "c") :test #'equalp)
"a"
```

Thus, I did this naive approach:

```
(defun so-question (str str-list)
  (if (member str str-list :test #'string=)
      nil
      str))
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Maybe using `member-if-not` and `:key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is more elegant; your "naive" solution might be more clear, but you could do this:

```lisp
(defun tweaked-member (needle haystack)
  (and (not (member needle haystack :test #'equalp)) needle))
```

```
CL-USER> (tweaked-member "a" '("a" "b" "c"))
NIL
CL-USER> (tweaked-member "a" '("b" "c"))
"a"
```

You could use `find` in place of `member`:

```lisp
(defun tweaked-member (needle haystack)
  (and (not (find needle haystack :test #'equalp)) needle))
```

I didn't notice until now that my version does not take a `:test` argument, as you asked. But:

```lisp
(defun tweaked-member (needle haystack &rest args)
  (and (not (apply #'member needle haystack args)) needle))
```

```
CL-USER> (tweaked-member "a" '("a" "b" "c") :test #'equalp)
NIL
CL-USER> (tweaked-member "a" '("b" "c") :test #'equalp)
"a"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun tweaked-member (&rest args)
  (if (apply #'member args) nil (car args)))
```

It is not more elegant, but it takes all keywords which `member` takes.

Comment: Did you try this on OP's examples?

Comment: ah - it is the other way round? I see ... it is the other way round...

Comment: It's nice that this takes keyword arguments, but `(tweaked-member "a" '("b" "c") :test #'equalp)` should return `"a"`.

Comment: And thanks to you for reminding me that OP used keyword arguments in the example invocations ;)

Comment: @adabsurdum welcome ;) - thank you for reminding me that OP wanted it the other way round :)